# Exchanging module values in AngularJS test

Tags: javascript, testing, angularjs, jasmine

I have a module with a `greet` factory attached to it:

```
angular.module('someModule', [])
  .factory('greet', function(name) {
    return function() {
      return 'Hi ' + name + '!';
    }
  });
```

This factory injects a `name` which is a value defined in some other module.

```
angular.module('someOtherModule', [])
  .value('name', 'example');
```

When testing this module, I would like to be able to change the value of my injectable `name` multiple times (once for each test) so that my tests can look something like:

```
// In my test file…

// Initialise the module I am testing `greet` upon, and mock the other module which has a `name` value
beforeEach(mocks.module('someModule', function ($provider) {
    $provider.value('name', 'Bob');
}));

var greet

beforeEach(mocks.inject(function ($injector) {
    greet = $injector.get('greet');
});

it('should say "Bob"', function () {
    expect(greet()).toBe('Hi Bob!');
});

// Now I need to change the `name` value to be "Bar" instead

it('should say "Bar"', function () {
    expect(greet()).toBe('Hi Bar!');
});
```

How is this possible?

The two modules are composed with my app module:

```
angular.module('app', ['someModule', 'someOtherModule'])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `$provide.value('name', 'Bob');` to inject the value.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('greet', function (name) {
    return function () {
        return 'Hi ' + name + '!';
    }
});

myApp.value('name', 'example');

describe('myApp', function () {
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));

    it('should say "Bob"', function () {
        module(function ($provide) {
            $provide.value('name', 'Bob');
        });
        angular.mock.inject(function ($injector) {
            var greet = $injector.get('greet');
            expect(greet()).toBe('Hi Bob!');
        })
    });

    it('should say "Bar"', function () {
        module(function ($provide) {
            $provide.value('name', 'Bar');
        });
        angular.mock.inject(function ($injector) {
            var greet = $injector.get('greet');
            expect(greet()).toBe('Hi Bar!');
        })
    });
});
```

I created a demo for you and hope it can shed some light!

***Updated***: demo

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mHcxz/)**</kbd>

Comment: In my example, `name` is a `value` on another module. It is being injected into my factory. So this will not work for me…

Comment: You'd better paste the code relating to `name`. It has to be a module, not a value. So it has to be a provider or something.

Comment: Why downvote? Downvote without giving a reason is not constructive.

Comment: I downvoted it because, initially, I believe you did not properly understand my question. I see you've vastly edited your answer now, so I will remove the downvote. Sorry about that. Could you demonstrate how you would do the tests I provided in my question (with tests against two names)?

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh For right now I don't have a solution without duplicating the code. sorry about that.

Comment: Duplicating the whole describe block? :-(

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh I guess so. I need to do more research coz `$provide.value('name', 'Bob');` doesn't work after the injector is initialized.

Comment: Let me know if you find anything. It's slightly annoying that this is the only way to do it. I don't want to have to create a new injector in every `it`.

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh I updated. And it should be a bit simplified. I don't think this should be considered as duplicating code since you have to setup module before doing inject(). And since by the design, the `name` module changes for different tests, so you have to re-inject to get the factory service every time.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working, but I had to make a slight change to how the name dependency was injected (pointed out in the comment below). Given the *app* code:

```js
angular.module("app", ["some", "other"]);

angular.module("some", []).factory('greet', function(name) { // name injected here
  return function() { // the name dependency moved from here up one function signature
    return 'Hi ' + name + '!';
  };
});

angular.module("other", []).value('name', 'example');
```

This is as DRY as I could make the test:

```js
describe("greet", function() {

  var provide = injector = greet = undefined;

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('app', function($provide) {
      provide = $provide;
    });
    inject(function($injector) {
      injector = $injector;
    });
    greet = function() {
      return injector.get('greet')();
    };
  });

  describe("#greet", function() {
    it("says Hi Bob", function() {
      provide.value('name', 'Bob');
      expect(greet()).toBe('Hi Bob!');
    });

    it("says Hi Biff", function() {
      provide.value('name', 'Biff');
      expect(greet()).toBe('Hi Biff!');
    });
  });

});
```